# Saving the address of a variable

Tags: c, pointers

I want to save the address of a variable in a clean way, so NO Compiler errors or warnings.
I've got something like this:

```
unsigned int a = 5;
unsigned int address = (unsigned int)&a;
```

But I get some compiler-warnings. If I write

```
unsigned int address = &a;
```

its also the wrong way. So what is the clean way(for a 32-bit architecture, need not to be running on a 64-bit platform), and without using standard-libraries!!

Comment: `unsigned int *address = &a;`

Comment: Why do you ask? Why don't you use pointers? What will you do with that address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pointers in c, which should be something like

```
int *address = &a;
```

Comment: @alabamajack it would be advisable to think about the possible solutions of a problem before automatically resorting to asking on SO...

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant sometimes its happens that you don't get forward

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
unsigned int a = 5;
unsigned int *address;

adress = &a;
```